# Integration in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, sympy

The code I have written to integrate is giving wrong results.I get the c_0,c_1,...c_4 to be zeros! What am I doing wrong? I am using simply 0.7.6 on a mac.

```
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x')
f = 1.0*sin(np.pi * x)
phi_0 = 1.0
phi_1 = 1.0*x
phi_2 = 1./2*(3*x**2-1)
phi_3 = 1./2*(5*x**3-3*x)
phi_4 = 1./8*(35*x**4-30*x**2+3)
c_0 = integrate(f*phi_0, (x, -1.0, 1.0))
c_1 = integrate(f*phi_1, (x, -1.0, 1.0))
c_2 = integrate(f*phi_2, (x, -1.0, 1.0))
c_3 = integrate(f*phi_3, (x, -1.0, 1.0))
c_4 = integrate(f*phi_4, (x, -1.0, 1.0))
print c_0
print c_1
print c_2
print c_3
print c_4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the need to import numpy as np, I don't see any problems in the most recent version (0.7.6). Some values are zero (as expected due to symmetry consideration) but others are not:

```
>>> print c_0
0
>>> print c_1
0.636619772367581
>>> print c_2
0
>>> print c_3
-0.330926260628403
>>> print c_4
0
```

Comment: I get zeros for all @smichr .

Comment: For me, >>> sympy.__version__  -> '0.7.6-git'. What do you get?

Comment: Also, check your value of np.pi. It is possible that it got set to 0 which would then make your `f` zero, too.

Comment: how can I check my version? I typed "sympy.__version__ -> " in my code but got an error. @smichr

Answer (score 1):

I agree with smichr. Everything appears to be fine as long as your import numpy. You can also use scipy but that is dependent on your preferences and needs.

```
from scipy.integrate import quad

quad(lambda x: x**2, 0, 1)
```

Comment: can I define x**2 prior to calling quad?

Comment: Yeah that's not a problem. For example lets say f(x) was defined to be x**2, you can say quad(f, -1, 1) and it should integrate that for you

Comment: how should I define f. before I would define x as symbolic variable and then define f. Now what should I use? lambda? @dparadis28

Comment: You could use lambdas or define a function (ex: def f(x): return x**2) and use f as an arg for the quad function as shown above; quad(f, -1, 1). Does this help point you in the right direction?